# How to remove all Hyperlinks from a .pages Document

Tags: macos, iwork-pages

I've got a `.pages` file that contains some copy-pasted text from a Website and therefore has a lot of hyperlinks behind certain words.

I know there is the option to *Make all hyperlinks inactive*, but what I actually want to do is **remove the links completely**, not just make them inactive.

Is there some way to do this without having to click each link and then uncheck *Enable as a hyperlink*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [forum thread](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/980162), there are some options:

> 1. I usually paste it into 'TextEdit'
>    and making sure that TexEdit is
>    displaying fonts as Plain Text. Then
>    copy the links or texts from TexEdit
>    and paste it into Pages.
> 2. Open the Inspector palette. Select the second last tab called "Link
>    Inspector", then highlight the link
>    itself. Click the "Enable as a
>    hyperlink" checkbox to off and it
>    will disappear.
> 3. In Pages preferences, there's an
>    option on the "Auto Correct" tab to
>    "Automatically detect email and web
>    addresses". Untick that and it
>    shouldn't happen if what you're
>    pasting contains a URL or an email
>    address.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. 2) and 3) don't work because the text is already there. 1) would remove the formatting it already has but seems like the most appropriate option.

Comment: @slhck: Yeah, (1) seems like the best possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

In Pages 5.2.2, one can remove (or add) a link by clicking "Format" which gives an option to "Add link" or "Remove link".  It really is very easy.

Comment: The point of this question was to not have to do it for each link individually.